# Why isn't booliean expression working

Tags: regex

I am using the following regular expression to filter some junk emails

```
\bNeotube\b | \bNeotubeTV\b
```

Here is a sample of the junk email header:

```
Return-path: <uranus@pschic.info>
Envelope-to: coben@jesusmylord.org
Delivery-date: Thu, 25 May 2017 14:18:58 +0200
Received: from [45.59.120.18] (port=30375 helo=pschic.info)
  by ok1057.kvchosting.com with esmtp (Exim 4.89)
 (envelope-from <uranus@pschic.info>)
 id 1dDrj8-0002X1-Se
 for coben@jesusmylord.org; Thu, 25 May 2017 14:18:58 +0200
From: "NeotubeTV" <uranus@pschic.info>
Date: Thu, 25 May 2017 06:58:18 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Free TV shows, Sports and New Movies on your TV In HD?
To: <coben@jesusmylord.org>
Message-ID: `
```

The above expression does not work. However, if I just use

```
\bNeotubeTV\b
```

the email is filtered. Why doesn't the above OR statement work?

Thanks for your help.
Chris

Comment: Remove the spaces. Or better, use `\bNeotube(?:TV)?\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have spaces around the `|` which is saying that you want include those spaces in your regex.